# PHP PDO returning false when executing prepared statement with parameters

Tags: php, sql, function, pdo, prepared-statement

I have been banging my head against this issue for the past three days. Seemingly no matter what I do, if I try and execute a prepared PDO statement while passing in parameters it will always return false.

```
function login($email,$password)

$outcome;
$conn;
$servername = ...
$username = ...
$password = ...
$database = ...

try {
    $conn = new PDO(...);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE );


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $outcome = "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    return $outcome;
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_email = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array($email));

$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo (json_encode($user));

...
```

I've tried using bindValue() and bindParam() to explicitly bind the $email variable to the placeholder, either way the $user variable will always evaluate to false. It should return the first row of the query results as an associative array.

Comment: If either the prepare or execute returns false, you should find out what the specific error was. Refer to documentation about error handling in PDO. For example, it could be that your MySQL user doesn't have privileges to query the `users` table, or it could be the `users` table doesn't exist in the database you have selected as your default database. It's fruitless to guess at the error, when the error message is easy to get.

Comment: Enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php then tell us what you get back.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I followed your example and no error is output, just the value from the $user variable that I am echoing which equals 'false'

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_email = :user_email";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_email', $email);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: No, this gives me the same result as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what it gives you. Once you see where the error is, you can go from there

```
<?php
function login($email,$password)
{
      $servername = 'localhost';
      $username = 'DB_USERNAME';
      $password = 'DB_PASSWORD';
      $database = 'DB_NAME';
      $charset = 'utf8mb4';

      $dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;charset=$charset";
      try
      {
          $opt = [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, ];
          $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
      }
      catch(PDOException $e)
      {
          echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
      }

      $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :user_email');
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_email', $email);
      if ($stmt->execute())
      {
          if ($user = $stmt->fetch())
          {
              echo (json_encode($user));
          } else {
              echo "Error, failed fetching data";
          }
      } else {
          echo "Error, failed executing query";
      }
 }
```